# Calculate the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{e^n}{n^2}x^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

The radius of convergence should be  $\frac{1}{e}$, but mine is $\infty$:

$$\frac{\frac{e^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{e^n}{n^2}} = \frac{e^{n+1}n^2}{(n+1)^2e^n} = \frac{e}{n+1}$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{e}{n+1}) = 0$$ $\Rightarrow$ radius of convergence $= \infty$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: If the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^2}$ is $k$ then the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(ex)^n}{n^2}$ is $\frac{k}{e}$.  And here $k=1$

Comment: You will never be a great elector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculated the limit in the wrong way: you have
$$\frac{e^{n+1}/(n+1)^2}{e^n/n^2}=\frac{e^{n+1}}{e^n}\cdot \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}$$
Now $(n+1)^2/n^2\to 1$ (see this as exercise) and it rests the constant part
$$e^{n+1}/e^n=e$$
Recalling that the radius of convergence is the inverse of this limit, you have the thesis.

Comment: Use braces around an exponent that's more than one character.  Corrected here.

Comment: where does ! come from. strange elector.

Comment: Im wondering about that too @Salahamam_Fatima

Comment: Should be right when replaced by ^2

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo. Now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The ratio test gives

$$\frac {1}{R}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac {e^{n+1}}{e^n}(\frac {n}{n+1})^2=e $$

The root test gives

$$\frac {1}{R}=\lim_{+\infty}e^ {1+2\frac{\ln (n)}{n}}=e $$

Answer (score 2):

If the ratio $=0$, then the series converges absolutely. Also, your calculation of ratio is wrong. It should read $en^2/(n+1)^2$, which $\to e$. In order that the power series converges, the ratio of convergence is $1/e$. If $|xe|=1$, we see $\sum_i n^{-2i} =\pi^2/6$, including the endpoints. And the interval of convergence is $|x| \leq 1/e$.

Comment: Not $e(n+1)^2/n^2 \rightarrow 0$.  That limit is $e$.

Comment: Sorry.... >< just corrected.